# Zip multiple directories Using Ionic Zip Library

Tags: c#

I'm trying to zip several folders with their content into one zip file using  Ionic Zip Library. The code below did created a zip file, however the folders were not added to it.

```
private void ZipFolder(List <string> folders, string pathToSaveZipFile)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (string itrFolder in folders)
            {
                zip.AddDirectory(itrFolder);
            }
            zip.Save(pathToSaveZipFile);
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddDirectory(string)` adds the files to the root, you need to use

```
zip.AddDirectory(itrFolder,  new DirectoryInfo(itrFolder).Name);
```

The second argument specifies the folder name within the ZIP.